# Pick line with highest value

Tags: perl, awk

Referring to the code below:

How do I pick the sample which has the highest value and output the whole line.

```
 Sample      Value      Sequence
 miR1        23213      atatgcgctcg
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
 miR1        3453       tctgctcg
 miR2        343        tctctgag
 miR2        34535      tctct
 miR2        4324       tctgagag
 ...
```

Output:

```
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
 miR2        34535      tctct
```

I guess I could do some sorting in excel, but is there a way to do this in perl or in the command line?

Comment: The *“sample with the highest value”* is clearly the second record. I guess you mean the sequences with the highest value for each sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR>1{ if (a[$1]<$2) {a[$1]=$2;b[a[$1]]=$0} else a[$1]} END {for (i in a) print b[a[i]]}' file
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
 miR2        34535      tctct
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -MList::Util=max -lane'
  $h{$F[0]}{$F[1]} = $_ }{
  print $h{$_}{ max keys %{$h{$_}} } for keys %h
' file
```

output

```
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
 miR2        34535      tctct
```

Comment: It only prints one line :/

Comment: @user3741035 I've copy/pasted the result.

Comment: @mpapec I liked it. So you'll have my vote. Though I would like to get your help on my attempt. I tried doing `perl -lane 'push @{$h{$F[0]}} , [@F[1..2]] }{ print join "\t", $_, @{$h{$_}} for (sort { $h{$b}[0] <=> $h{$a}[0] } keys %h)' file` and then taking a slice of the output. But struggling to print the hash of array of array.

Comment: @jaypal this is HoAoA (three levels), so you're missing one, `perl -wlane'
  push @{$h{$F[0]}} , [$F[1], $_] }{
  print for map { my $k=$_; my ($m) = sort{ $h{$k}[$b][0] <=> $h{$k}[$a][0] } 0 .. $#{$h{$k}}; $h{$k}[$m][1] } keys %h
' file`

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code will split your input file by `\s+` and use the 1st column as a key in a hash which will take the largest value for that key as it's final value:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;

open my $in, '<', 'in.txt';

my (%data, @split, %keep);

while (<$in>){
    chomp;
    next if /^Sample/;
    s/^\s//;
    @split = split(/\s+/);
    if ( (not exists $data{$split[0]} ) || (abs $data{$split[0]} < abs $split[1] ) ) {
        $data{$split[0]} = $split[1];
        $keep{$split[0]} = [ $split[1], $split[2] ];                     
    }

}

print "$_\t@{$keep{$_}}\n" for sort keys %keep;
```

---

```
miR1    324235 atatctcgct
miR2    34535 tctct
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -lane '
push @{$h{$F[0]}}, [$F[1], $_] }{ 
print $_->[1] for map { (sort { $b->[0] <=> $a->[0] } @$_)[0] } values %h' file
```

**Output:**

```
 miR2        34535      tctct
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use sort,

```
$ sort -k 2,2n file | tac | head -2
 miR1        324235     atatctcgct
 miR2        34535      tctct
```

Comment: You need to add `head -n 2` to get the two line, but what if there are more variables? Eks `miR3` `mirR4 `and `mirRN`

Answer (score 0):

The below awk command will give only the line with maximum value.

```
 awk 'BEGIN {IFS= "[ ]*";maxVal=1 } NR>1{ if(maxVal < $2) maxVal = $0 } END {print maxVal  }'  inputFile.txt
```

output:

```
miR1   23213   atatgcgctcg
```

Comment: I've corrected your output (which was wrong for the code). I think the OP wanted the highest value for each sample though.